# Syncing incremental data with ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl, data-analysis, azure-synapse

In Synapse I've setup 3 different pipelines. They all gather data from different sources (SQL, REST and CSV) and sink this to the same SQL database.

Currently they all run during the night, but I already know that the question is coming of running it more frequently. I want to prevent that my pipelines are going to run through all the sources while nothing has changed in the source.

Therefore I would like to store the last succesfull sync run of each pipeline (or pipeline activity). Before the next start of each pipeline I want to create a new pipeline, a 4th one, which checks if something has changed in sources. If so, it triggers the execution of one, two or all three the pipelines to run.

I still see some complications in doing this, so I'm not fully convinced on how to do this. So all help and thoughts are welcome, don't know if someone has experience in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is (at least in part) the subject of the following Microsoft tutorial:
[Incrementally load data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Blob storage using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal)

You're on the correct path - the crux of the issue is creating and persisting "watermarks" for each source from which you can determine if there have been any changes. The approach you use may be different for different source types. In the above tutorial, they create a stored procedure that can store and retrieve a "last run date", and use this to intelligently query tables for only rows modified after this last run date. Of course this requires the cooperation of the data source to take note of when data is inserted or modified.

If you have a source that cannot by intelligently queried in part (e.g. a CSV file) you still have options to use things like the [Get Metadata Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to e.g. query the `lastModified` property of a source file (or even its `contentMD5` if using blob or ADLGen2) and compare this to a value saved during your last run (You would have to pick a place to store this, e.g. an operational DB, Azure Table or small blob file) to determine whether it needs to be reprocessed.

If you want to go crazy, you can look into streaming patterns (might require dabbling in HDInsights or getting your hands dirty with Azure Event Hubs to trigger ADF) to move from the scheduled trigger to an automatic ingestion as new data appears at the sources.